# How to sign xml file with usb token in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, security, digital-signature

As Microsoft provided a guide about signing XML document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-sign-xml-documents-with-digital-signatures. But it did not mention about using USB token containing digital signature.

Comment: USB token is a certificate (contains key) used for encryption.  You need to read the USB encryption key and use instead of the key shown in the attachment.

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng . Is there any way to automatically enter password for key in USB token? I am going to build an application that automatically signs XML file.

Comment: Do not know.  The USB has it own built in app that accepts the password.